# How do I extract the vertices indices from an Geometrical nodes model that belong to a given edge (always a start and end vertice)

Tags: bmesh

I am looking to retrieve al the starting and ending vertices per edge of an object (standard box in this case).
For this I have created the following code:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np

# get a reference to the active object
mesh_obj = bpy.context.active_object

# create a new bmesh object
bm = bmesh.new()

# initialize the bmesh object using the mesh data
bm.from_mesh(mesh_obj.data)

#Extract all vertex coords and package for export
vertices = np.empty((0,3),int)
for v in bm.verts:
    vertex = np.array([v.co.x, v.co.y, v.co.z])
    vertices = np.append(vertices,[vertex], axis=0)
    
edges = np.empty((0,2),int)
for e in bm.edges:
    edge = np.array(e.verts)
    edges = np.append(edges,[edge], axis=0)
    

print(vertices)
print(edges)

bm.free
```

The result however is:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1. -1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.]
 [-1.  1. -1.]
 [-1. -1.  1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]]
[[<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3D68), index=5>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3DD8), index=7>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3C88), index=1>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3D68), index=5>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3C50), index=0>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3C88), index=1>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3DD8), index=7>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3DA0), index=6>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3CC0), index=2>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3CF8), index=3>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3D30), index=4>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3D68), index=5>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3CC0), index=2>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3DA0), index=6>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3C50), index=0>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3CC0), index=2>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3DD8), index=7>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3CF8), index=3>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3DA0), index=6>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3D30), index=4>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3D30), index=4>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3C50), index=0>]
 [<BMVert(0x0000020D001D3CF8), index=3>
  <BMVert(0x0000020D001D3C88), index=1>]]
```

The results of the coordinates of the vertices are fine but I just don't see how te get the indices of the vertices belonging to an edge.
Why are the results of the indices not just the index number but `{BMVert(@@@@)` ?
How can I obtain just the index numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For edges try this instead :**

---

```
import bpy


edges = bpy.context.selected_objects[0].data.edges

verts_pairs = [list(e.vertices) for e in edges]


for pair in verts_pairs:
#     
    print(pair)
#
```

---

**For a box in this case output looks like :**

```
[2, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 3]
[3, 2]
[6, 2]
[3, 7]
[7, 6]
[4, 6]
[7, 5]
[5, 4]
[0, 4]
[5, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much .